# Aggregation function is different in version 8.4 and 9.5?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like this.

```
SELECT companies.id, companies.code, MAX(disclosures.filed_at) disclosure_filed_at
FROM \"companies\" INNER JOIN \"disclosures\" ON \"disclosures\".\"company_id\" = \"companies\".\"id\"
GROUP BY companies.id
```

This query works in Postgresql `9.5.2`, but it failed in version `8.4.20` with an error.

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "companies.code" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

If I add `companies.code` to `GROUP BY` clause, then it works. But when I select by `companies.*`, I can't group by `companies.*`.

Should I write all columns in version `8.4` to use `*`?

Answer (score 1):

The Postgres behavior is supported by the ANSI standard.  The reason is that the `id` not only defines each row in `companies`, but it is defined to do so (using a `unique` or `primary key` constraint, although I'm not sure if this works in Postgres for a `unique` constraint).

Hence, the database knows that it can safely refer to any other column from the same row.  This is called "functional dependency".

This feature has also now been added to MySQL (documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)).  You might find that documentation easier to follow than the Postgres [description](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

> When `GROUP BY` is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it
>   is not valid for the `SELECT` list expressions to refer to ungrouped
>   columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column
>   is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would
>   otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped
>   column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a
>   subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the
>   ungrouped column.